# Difference between "Self" and elided lifetime

Tags: rust, closures, traits, lifetime

Don't know how to describe, but here is the minimal reproducing snippet (also on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1d17697ba10113961cdcc8f55ed508d5)):

```rust
struct Ctx(Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&mut MockCtx)>>);

struct MockCtx<'a>(&'a mut Ctx);

impl MockCtx<'_> {
    // this works
    fn push<F: 'static + Fn(&mut MockCtx)>(&mut self, f: F) {
        self.0.0.push(Box::new(f));
    }
}

trait Push {
    fn push<F: 'static + Fn(&mut Self)>(&mut self, f: F);
}

impl Push for MockCtx<'_> {
    // fn push<F: 'static + Fn(&mut Self)>(&mut self, f: F) {    (1)
    fn push<F: 'static + Fn(&mut MockCtx)>(&mut self, f: F) { // (2)
        MockCtx::push(self, f)
    }
}
```

If I take (1), compiler reports

```
expected a `Fn<(&mut MockCtx<'_>,)>` closure, found `F`
```

and recommand to add explicit lifetime to restrict. If I do so or simply take (2), compiler reports

```
impl has stricter requirements than trait
```

The truth is I do not understand the problem from starting point... I understand what is lifetime and simple "outlive" rules, and to me compiler should have no worry about `'a` for these code so far, because that can only be a thing when these `Box<dyn Fn>` actually get called.

Thanks for any replying and explaining!

Comment: I suspect you should put the generic on the trait itself, not the method: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9dc7beb4543caa7a7fb743610d012146)

Comment: @Jmb that indeed compiles, but the trait also become totally useless with a function type parameter...

Comment: Note that having the generic on the method means that the trait is not [object-safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects), so the trait is "completely useless" _with_ a function type parameter…

Comment: Another solution is to get rid of the generic completely and use dynamic dispatch: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9cbbdb319f5ed4420ab41580535ad2a0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is understandably a little opaque, because several lifetimes are elided. It should become a little more clear if we write those out.

Let's first look at the container:

```
struct Ctx(Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&mut MockCtx)>>);
```

This is short for:

```
struct Ctx(Vec<Box<dyn for<'a, 'b> Fn(&'a mut MockCtx<'b>) + 'static>>);
```

The `'static` requires that any closure you put in the container must own its data. It cannot refer to other data that depends on a lifetime. The [elided lifetime is `'static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes) because `Box` has no lifetime parameters.

The construct `for<'a, 'b> Fn(&'a mut MockCtx<'b>)` is a [higher rank trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html), or HRTB for short. This means that any closure you put in the container must be able to accept a mutable reference with any lifetime to a `MockCtx<'_>` with any lifetime parameter. Note for later that there are two lifetime parameters here.

Now, let's go to the impl:

```
impl MockCtx<'_> {
    fn push<F: 'static + Fn(&mut MockCtx)>(&mut self, f: F);
}
```

This is short for:

```
impl MockCtx<'_> {
    fn push<F: 'static + for<'a, 'b> Fn(&'a mut MockCtx<'b>)>(&mut self, f: F);
}
```

The requirements on the closure are the same as for the container. No conflicts. But note that the closure must accept types *other than* `Self`. It must accept a mutable reference to a `MockCtx<'_>` with a different lifetime.

Now let's go to the trait:

```
trait Push {
    fn push<F: 'static + Fn(&mut Self)>(&mut self, f: F);
}
```

This is short for:

```
trait Push {
    fn push<F: 'static + for<'a> Fn(&'a mut Self)>(&mut self, f: F);
}
```

This is going to conflict. A closure given to `Push` can only be called with a reference to `Self`, of any lifetime. But a closure that we store in our container must accept some types other than `Self`. There is a whole range of `Self`-like types that have different lifetime parameters that the closure needs to accept for our container.

Now, we can explain why the two attempts failed. #1 fails because the closure in the trait and the trait impl can only accept `Self`, but we're attempting to store it in a container that holds closures that can accept `MockCtx<'_>` of any lifetime. #2 fails because the trait only requires the closure accept `Self`, but our trait impl tries to accept a more restrictive set of closures that can accept `MockCtx<'_>` for any lifetime.

There are several ways to fix this, but they all amount to fixing this disagreement on the bounds for the argument of the closure.

One way is to explicitly accept the full range of types in the closure bound. You have to mention types other than `Self`. So, for example, you can mention the concrete types:

```
trait Push {
    fn push<F: 'static + Fn(&mut MockCtx<'_>)>(&mut self, f: F);
}
```

[See here.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=36a7fcc430aa29ba6f819e1e871f607a)

Using a nightly feature of trait aliases, you could use a common name for all the requirements:

```
trait MockFn = 'static + Fn(&mut MockCtx<'_>);
trait Push {
    fn push<F: MockFn>(&mut self, f: F);
}
```

[See here.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8695f72ef962d78776a290232b06a706)

Using a nightly feature of generic associated types, you could also make the trait slightly more general:

```
trait Push {
    type SelfLike<'a>;
    fn push<F: 'static + Fn(&mut Self::SelfLike<'_>)>(&mut self, f: F);
}
```

[See here.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=894e2bb248f6ccee76143e6d845a2a19)

Alternatively, as @Jmb says in the comments, you can make the closure a generic parameter on the trait:

```
trait Push<F> {
    fn push(&mut self, f: F);
}
```

[See here.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18cb1bc1bd49071fea7074fe370be031)

This is a relatively clean approach. It is asserted in the comments that this is useless, but I don't think it is.